# Python scheduler: how to advice that a scheduled job is running with Flask

Tags: python, flask, events, scheduler

I have an application that runs on Python Flask and contains an aps scheduler that run a job every 30 seconds.

A service used for my API needs to know if the job scheduled and managed by the scheduler is running or not, but I can't access to the instance of the scheduler (it has been declared on **main** file of Flask).

Any idea?

Comment: Any idea ? Yeah, maybe. Show your code so we can provide concrete advice. But the solution could be as simple as importing the instance of apsscheduler eg: `from main import scheduler` - or whatever it is called in your main.py file.

Comment: It seems that from __main__it is not possible to import the scheduler...but you get me an idea...i could use the singleton for the scheduler...

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:
Why you not use sleep?
I think you can delay that with

```
time.sleep(30)
```

And use for to loop that!

Way 2:
You can use run file with cron job of operating system

Comment: i need to know if the job is running because if a GET request comes from web, my API i have to reply with a message "System Busy" and your  2 way don't solve my problem